# ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed

Tags: log4j, sparql, log4j2, jena

I download Apache Jena,and follow the tutorial of SPARQL in https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql_query1.html,
I type this command:

```
sparql.bat --data=vc-db-1.rdf --query=q1.rq
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsxVu.png)
then I get this.

```
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '6d5380c2' at 'null' in 'null'
--------------------------------
| x                            |
================================
| <http://somewhere/JohnSmith> |
--------------------------------
```

It dosen't affect the command executing, but still want to fix this "ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed".

I searched about this error, find it seems to be connected with log4j which I am not familiar with.

Comment: Hi - there is a fix for this in the next release : edit the bat file and remove the "file:" part of line 14 setting LOGGING.

https://github.com/apache/jena/issues/1911

Please respond here if that works for you.

Comment: Appreciate,It did work for my problem@AndyS